# translate just the content of a specific div

Tags: jquery, google-translate

On page load I need translate to french (or maybe german) language only a specific div's content and place the translation as a content of next divs.

Is it possible using any free google api, or similar ?

```
<div class="prim">apple</div>
<div></div>

<div class="prim">car</div>
<div></div>

<div class="prim">sky</div>
<div></div>
```

js - something like:

```
$(".prim").each(function(){
    var a = $(this).text();
    var b = a.translated;
    $(this).next().html(b);
});
```

Comment: check this, it may help you - https://davidwalsh.name/google-translate-api

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar, I saw this page, but below the header `Click one of the links below to translate the text from one language to another.` links to translate doesn't work. Please check.

Comment: @bonaca: Google Translate is no longer free and is a paid service. You may want to look at this instead -- https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/translator/getstarted.aspx